# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair when trying to make call to web service

Tags: java, apache, http

I am making an HTTP call like this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

//ent is MultipartEntityBuilder ent 
httppost.setEntity(ent.build());
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);****
```

I am getting the error at the line of code with the ****

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:279)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:257)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:132)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:349)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:365)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:221)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:199)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:87)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:109)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:84)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:109)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
```

I am not quite sure what is causing this. Could someone please tell me what is causing this? I am making a rest call to a web service

Answer (score 0):

It appears you make an http connection and get redirected to https, which you are not handling. You are getting an SSL error. It cannot create the Diffie Hellman pair, which is an early part of SSL handshake.

Comment: How do I handle this exception? I was able to make calls normally earlier

Comment: Make sure the url is http, not https. If you are being auto-redirected then you need to write code to handle SSL handshake. Google `SSL handshake java`